# How to minimize and maximize internet explorer in ASP.NET and JAVASCRIPT?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer, events

I have a grid view that shows various information. If this returns empty grid, the browser should be minimized, if he has any information the browser will be maximized

Is there any way to do this through JavaScript?

Comment: I would hate web developer who wrote code that messes with my windows. I can't find any remotely valid reasons to do that.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible with server-side code or Javascript.  However, you can change the size of the window (although I would recommend not doing this as it's an awkward user experience).

Comment: How can I do this? I need to minimize the browser.

Comment: @user1792343 I don't think you can actually minimize the browser. You can just make the window very small--which is likely to just annoy your users.

Answer (score 0):

Use the DOM / JQuery to find out how many rows are in the grid, and then use the maximize / minimize methods off the current Window...

Comment: Outside the current window? how can I do this?